# Images uploading from media going in wrong folder

Tags: images, uploads

I am uploading images from Media section of WordPress. The images are uploading in 2016/12 instead of 2017/08. I checked for media setting in Settings > Media and Organise my uploads into month- and year-based folders option is selected.

Also when I create a new page and upload an image from there then it goes in 2017/08 folder.

Can anyone suggest me how I can fix it. I searched for this and didn't found solution for images issue uploading from Media section.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The date of the folder corresponds to the date the post was created as opposed to the date the media is uploaded.

Comment: This seems like a "feature"... but it does not seem to happen in recent WordPress versions. Has someone treated it as a bug? If so, when did the behaviour change... because I want the old behaviour :-)